# Differences between $L^p$ and $\ell^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Could someone explain some differences between the $L^p$ and $\ell^p$ spaces? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just googled the question title; see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). Also, sorry I used the wrong small $l$ in your question, I only saw that half the way through the article.

Comment: Thanks. I had found this before I posted the question too but I am still confused...or to be more exact, I am not sure if what I've been reading is correct. What exactly is the definition of the L^p space?

Comment: Perhaps user should tell us what she got by looking these up... and why she thinks it may be wrong.

Comment: $\ell^p$ is the same as $L^p$ using the measure space $\mathbb N$ with the counting measure.

Comment: On the other hand, $\ell^p$ is not isomorphic to $L^p([0,1])$.  The latter contains a subspace isomorphic to infinite dimensional Hilbert space, whereas the former does not.  But I don't remember the proof.

Comment: @GEdgar, from what I have read, it seems to me that an L^p space consists of (real/complex-valued?) functions and an l^p space consists of sequences (of real/complex values?) and the norm for both is the p-norm. I was not sure if this was the general case or if I have understood it correctly. I don't know much--I have taken just a semester of elementary analysis and have not learned about measure yet. By the way, thanks for all of the helpful comments and replies. Also, just curious: why did you assume I was a girl?

Comment: @user, if he had used a masculine pronoun would you have asked why he had assumed you were a boy?

Comment: @Christopher, yes :)

Comment: Where is this famous masculine/feminine pronoun? I can't find it.  By the way, despite my suggestive name, I am actually a cat (will not reveal which gender).

Answer (score 15):

Typically, $\ell^p$ is used to indicate a $p$-summable discrete set of values. For example, $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z}^{+})$ is the set of complex-valued sequences $\{(a_n)\}$ such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}} |a_n|^p < \infty$.

$L^p$ is typically used to indicate $p$-summable functions (with respect to some measure) on a non-discrete measure space, such as the usual $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, the set of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^p \, dx < \infty$.

The main point is that they are mathematically different notation for the same concept. If we think of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ as a discrete measure space and take the uniform measure on it, then a complex-valued sequence $(a_n)$ is a complex-valued measurable function on $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Comment: Might worth mentioning: the major difference between $\ell^p$ and $\mathcal{L}^p$ is that functions in $\mathcal{L}^p$ can have local fluctuations, while functions in $\ell^p$ cannot. This difference comes from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an atomic measure space while in general a measure space, on which we build $\mathcal{L}^p$, can be much more complicated.

Comment: @Christopher, sounds really good. Let me digest this :)

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused by the notation here. I've seen $\ell^p, \ell^p(\mathbb{N}), \ell^p(\mathbb{Z}), \ell^p(\mathbb{R})$ and even $\ell^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$. I've understood that $\ell^p=\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$, but is there any restriction on the index set, or e.g. what does it mean when we have $\ell^p(K)$ and $K$ is uncountable?

Comment: @Christopher.L $K$ has to be a measure space. Then $\ell^p(K)$ is the set of measurable functions on $K$ with finite $\ell^p$ integral.

Answer (score 8):

Of course, Christopher's answer is correct ($\ell^p$ is just a particular instance of a Lebesgue space $L^p$), but there are two other implicit questions here: how are the spaces $\ell^p$ and $L^p$ different. and what role could $p$ play?

This depends on what exactly you mean by $L^p$. Perhaps you could be thinking of either $L^p([0,1])$, or $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. For a fixed choice of $p$, these spaces aren't all that different, but if you consider the *scale* of $L^p$ spaces (that is, if you consider all $p \in (0,\infty)$), you start to see some differences. In particular, if $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$, then $L^q([0,1])$ is contained in $L^p([0,1])$, by Hölder's inequality (so the $L^p([0,1])$ scale is decreasing). For $p=1$ and $q=\infty$, this is just the fact that a bounded function on $[0,1]$ is integrable. However, there are no containment relations between the spaces $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. In this sense, $L^p([0,1])$ and $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ are different.

On the other hand, thinking now about the spaces $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$, the situation is a bit like $L^p([0,1])$ but *reversed* - if $1 \leq p < q < \infty$, then $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ is contained in $\ell^q(\mathbb{N})$, and so the $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ scale is increasing. For $p=1$ and $q=\infty$, this is the fact that a summable sequence is bounded. In this sense, $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ is different to both $L^p([0,1])$ and $L^p(\mathbb{R})$!

More generally, what I've said remains true if I replace $[0,1]$ with a measure space of finite measure and $\mathbb{N}$ with a granular measure space - that is, a measure space such that the measure of any nonempty measurable set is bounded below by some positive constant.

I'm sure there are some more subtle differences between $\ell^p$ and $L^p$ as Banach spaces (see for example Stephen Montgomery-Smith's comment) but I don't know much about this.

Comment: Great points, Alex! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it right, is Hilbert space an l^2 space?

Comment: L^2 spaces are Hilbert spaces, but there are lots of other examples of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Yep, $L^2$ spaces (for any measure space, so this includes $\ell^2$) are Hilbert spaces. The converse is also sort of true - every Hilbert space is *isomorphic to* an $L^2$ space. Contrary to what some people believe, this doesn't mean that Hilbert space theory is trivial!

(edit: I didn't mean to put down soup's comment - there are plenty of other examples of Hilbert spaces, they are all isomorphic to $L^2$ spaces, but isomorphism is too coarse to be useful sometimes)

Comment: @AlexAmenta Isn't that just for separable Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @soup here I admit partial ignorance: I remember being told once that in the non-separable case you can take $L^2$ of a measure space that is more badly behaved (probably itself non-separable). I don't know where to find a reference though - I'll chase it up in a few days when I have a chance, but otherwise I'm happy to be shown wrong

Comment: @user: All finite-dimensional Euclidean Spaces are Hilbert Spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Conclusion : Lp is a function Space and ℓp is a Sequence Space.
When Lp 's domain is natural number set then Lp and ℓp are quite same otherwise Lp is a big space.

Answer (score 1):

Either L or ℓ denotes the first alphabetic letter of Lebesgue. According to the definitions, there are interpretations for both L^p spaces and ℓ^p space. Please note that Frigyes Riesz named L^p spaces with adding the pulral "s" to the word "space". Mr. Riesz proved the L^2 spaces and ℓ^2 space are isomorphic. Of course, ℓ^2 space is the Hilbert space.

1.L^p (function) spaces

L^p spaces are function spaces defined using a natural generalization of the p-norm for finite-dimensional vector spaces. L^p spaces is called Lebesgue spaces, named after Henri Lebesgue.

2.ℓ^p (sequence) space

The above-mentioned p-norm can be extended to vectors that have an infinite number of components (sequences), which yields ℓ^p space. ℓ^p space is the sequence space consisting of the p-power summable sequences with the p-norm. In addition, it has bounded sequences.

However, some mathematicians used both L^p spaces and ℓ^p spaces to mention the Banach space, and both L^2 spaces and ℓ^2 space for the Hilbert space interchangeably (because infinite-dimensional vectors are used in L^p function spaces sometimes even though the usage is not strict in the math). The mathematicians have avoided the subtle difference of the two concepts. It makes people confused sometimes.